# Mongodb aggregate with cond and query value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm new to mongodb. I need to know how it is possible to query item for set to the value with aggregate

Data

```
[
  {
    "_id" : "11111",
    "parent_id" : "99",
    "name" : "AAAA"
  },
  {
    "_id" : "11112",
    "parent_id" : "99",
    "name" : "BBBB"
  },
  {
    "_id" : "11113",
    "parent_id" : "100",
    "name" : "CCCC"
  },
  {
    "_id" : "11114",
    "parent_id" : "99",
    "name" : "DDDD"
  }
]
```

mongoshell

### Assume $check is false

```js
db.getCollection('test').aggregate(
  [
    {
      "$group": {
        "_id": "$id",
        //...,
        "item": {
          "$last": {
            "$cond": [
              {"$eq": ["$check", true]},
              "YES",
              * * ANSWER **,
              }
            ]
          }
        },
      }
  ]
)
```

So i need the result for item is all the name contain with same parent_id as string of array

Expect result

```
[
  {
    "_id" : "11111",
    "parent_id" : "99",
    "name" : "AAAA",
    "item" : ["AAAA","BBBB","DDDD"]
  },

  {
    "_id" : "11112",
    "parent_id" : "99",
    "name" : "BBBB",
    "item" : ["AAAA","BBBB","DDDD"]
  },

  {
    "_id" : "11113",
    "parent_id" : "100",
    "name" : "CCCC",
    "item" : ["CCCC"]
  },

  {
    "_id" : "11114",
    "parent_id" : "99",
    "name" : "DDDD",
    "item" : ["AAAA","BBBB","DDDD"]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

[Sample live demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NYXUj8xElHY)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$parent_id",
      "item": {
        "$push": "$name"
      },
      "data": {
        "$push": {
          "_id": "$_id",
          "name": "$name"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$data"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": "$data._id",
      "parent_id": "$_id",
      "name": "$data.name",
      "item": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks man it work ! , But can i ask you for more information please ,
1.How your code combine with $cond (condition) ?

Comment: First I'm grouping the item based on parent id, also storing the name and id in data then unwinding the data. I'd recommend you to play with the sample demo that I've shared by modifying each stages.